# Google Sheet data update before opening document

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Is there a way to update spreadsheet data automatically before opening the spreadsheet ?

Let's develop a little bit. In a main Spreadsheet I'm doing some IMPORTRANGE to get data from 2 other Spreadsheets (these data are refreshed twice a day). Then I used the imported data to present a kind of summary / dashboard with some complex formulas.

When I open the main spreadsheet, it takes looooong time to update.
I noticed that this long time is driven by the change of imported data.
Is there a way to do this update offline and not trigger a calculation when opening the document ?

Hope I'm clear, don't hesitate to contact me for further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done with a script, but this is not my area (I found a solution on an external link, but don't want to post it here):

```
function myFunction() {
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A1').setValue('IMPORTRANGE('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/abcd123abcd123', 'sheet1!A:B')')
}
```

Then within the current project's triggers, select a 'time-driven' event source based on minutes of your choice.